# Serious bug in Android 4.4.4_r2: BOOT_COMPLETED Intent not always sent after boot

Tags: android, bootcompleted

There seems to be a serious bug in Android 4.4.4_r2:

[BOOT_COMPLETED not always sent bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78484)

Causing BOOT_COMPLETED Intent not to be sent. Does anyone know if this issue can be fixed on an Android 4.4.4_r2 device without building and flashing a custom built rom? Why does it not seem to affect anyone else than me, or a few users?

*P.S. I first posted the question on Android Enthusiasts, but they say it is a programming question so I posted it here also. D.S.*

Comment: It seems like you already have an answer, at point **5**. `5. patch to fix it. ...`

Comment: Yes you are right about the patch. Unfortunately I can't build and flash a new rom myself. What I really meant was, is it fixable without building my own Android-build? Is there an update or such?

Comment: Maybe, you can remove the support for Android 4.4.4 and minTarget a higher Android version?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a programming problem, but more of a defect device rom problem. I would like to fix my Android 4.4.4 device. The people at Android Enthusiast thought it was a programming problem though so they pointed me here.

Comment: You might want to try the [Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/) forum.

Comment: I did that, but they say it is for End-users only, and that only programmers have the necessary knowledge for this.

Comment: What about changing your ROM with a stock one or a custom one which doesn't have this problem?

Comment: I can't flash it myself. Manufacturer have to do it as far as I know. It is a Pipo X8 device with stock rom.

Comment: You can flash it yourself. Just google for getting how to. Most likely you'll find some help on the xda forum.

Comment: OK, but do I not have to go into som (unknown) boot loader mode, to flash? Can they help with that on XDA?

Comment: Yes, of course. You have to install a Recovery manager, first. You'll find all the explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error wasn't caused by the aforementioned KitKat bug. That bug instead seemed to affect the Package Manager as stated in the headline.

The bug was instead mentioned here, and seems to be an undocumented behaviour/issue in Android 3.1+:
[Boot-completed-regression](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/05/boot-completed-regression.html)